# IOS: how to hold my data in first view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm developing a program which has two view controller.
First view have one button and one textfield. 
Also Second view  same with first.

When i write anyword into textfield  then  i'm pressing to button  in view1 .
then i'm passing to view 2. then i'm turning back to first view how is pressing to button in view 2. My word has clear in the first view. How to hold word into textfield when to passing proccesing. 
Thank You very much,
Regards,
Bekir Yaylacı

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please post your code for First View Controller.

Comment: are you clearing the text of `UITextField` in -viewWillAppear or somewhere else in View1?

Comment: I didnt write any code. I only use drag and drop object. http://s31.postimg.org/4p0fclfnf/storyview.jpg

Comment: Share your textfiled storyboard attributes inspector screenshot.Atleast this will help us understand more on your problem

Comment: @user2188063 Did my answer fix your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is use delegates for backward passing of data

Refer simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios link for passing data from C to A controller.

Check basic-delegate-example link.

Another way is by posting notification. for backward passing of data

Check Comunicate-Two-Views link.

Comment: That's way too much for such a simple thing.

Comment: Also, please write self-contained answers, if you link to certain knowledge, then include the important points in your answer.

Comment: use delegate to pass the data btween vc

Comment: I'm creating dynamic object(text field ,label etc.) in the first view. when i showing to second view then i'm turning back first view. All objects having clear in the view1.

Comment: Yes we know. Check my answer.

Comment: can you show the first vc code  if you are creating dynamic lable and text field every time you create new objects so that's why it clear the value of text field